# javascript round robin url click

Tags: javascript, java, php

i want to implement url click link random method by use javascript.

for example,  if visitor A,B,C,D visited my site

and if click url link i want visitor visit my two website example1.com and example2.com  randomly.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="140,350,890,440" href="http://somesite.com" target="_blank">
```

i found some javascript with array method but how can i modify it and can adopt to my case?

```
<SCRIPT Language="Javascript">
<!--
function Randomlink()
{
    Url = new Array;
    Url[0] = "http://www.ccm.net/index.php3";
    Url[1] = "http://www. ccm.net/wifi";
    Url[2] = "http://www. ccm.net/php";
    Url[3] = "http://www. ccm.net/forum/";

    Chooselink = Math.round(Math.random() * (Url.length+1));
    window.open(Url[Chooselink],'_blank');
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Using Math.round() in this algorithm does not give you uniform distribution.  See examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need JavaScript for this?  If you are using php, it can be done there.

```
$sitenum = rand(1,2);

print <<<END
<area shape="rect" coords="140,350,890,440" href="http://somesite$sitenum.com" target="_blank">
END;
```

Comment: my simple website is only consist of html file not php. so possible solution is use javascript. thanks

Comment: Ok.  You tagged your question with php so I assumed you were using that also.